# Problems with simple Cypher Query: complicated match statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4J and Cypher and decided to play around with the Movie sample data that is provided when installing Neo4J desktop.

I want to run a very simple query, namely to retrieve the titles of the movies which involved 3 people, ***Liv Tyler, Charlize Theron, and Bonnie Hunt***. Matching up two people is not a problem (see the code below) but including a third one is difficult.

In SQL this wouldn't be a problem for me, but Cypher causes serious headaches. Here is the query so far:

```
MATCH (Person {name: "Liv Tyler"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(Person {name: "Bonnie Hunt"}) 
RETURN  movie.title AS Title
```

I've tried to use `AND` statements, but nothing works. 
So how to include ***Charlize Theron*** in this query?

Comment: Note that you're not using labels here. All labels must be prepended with `:`, so you should be using something like `(:Person {name: "Liv Tyler"})`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use multiple patterns to match three or more connections to a single node.**

You can use the variable `movie` which you are using in your query to refer same `Movie` node to include the pattern `(:Person {name: "Charlize Thero"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)`.

```
MATCH (:Person {name: "Liv Tyler"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(:Person {name: "Bonnie Hunt"}),
(:Person {name: "Charlize Theron"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie) 
RETURN  movie.title AS Title
```

**You can also rewrite the above query as follows:**

```
MATCH (:Person {name: "Liv Tyler"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie),
    (:Person {name: "Bonnie Hunt"})-[:DIRECTED]->(movie),
    (:Person {name: "Charlize Theron"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie) 
RETURN  movie.title AS Title
```

Comment: Many thanks for these suggestions! I had gone down this route but didn't get any results. Turned out the way in which the graph is visualized was misleading. Anyhow, thanks again! :)

Comment: Because there is no such pattern in the database. To clear there is no movie `(IN THE DATABASE)`  DIRECTED by **Bonnie Hunt**  in which these two actors ACTED.

Comment: Try this: `MATCH (:Person {name: "Liv Tyler"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie), (:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-[:DIRECTED]->(movie), (:Person {name: "Charlize Theron"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie) RETURN movie.title AS Title`

Comment: Make sure you're using `:Person` in that query! Otherwise, as it is now, this won't work as you're using a `Person` variable for all three persons which won't match to anything!

Comment: Thanks for pointing, didn't notice `:` while copying from the question.

Comment: I'm still struggeling with the inclusion of several Match statements. What if I want to create a query which returns all the names of actors who were involved in two particular movies? With a different dataset I tried something like this (see below), but that didn't work:                                                        
MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie {title: "Forrest Gump"}),
(actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie {title: " The Devil's Advocate"}) 
RETURN  actor.name AS Name

Answer (score 0):

If you have some arbitrary number of actors (parameterized), where you can't hardcode the :Person nodes in question, you can instead match on :Person nodes with their name in the parameter list, then filter based on the count of patterns found (you want to make sure all of the persons who acted in the movie are counted).

But if we do that first for directors, then we have some movie matches already, and can apply an `all()` predicate on the list of actors to ensure they all acted in the movie.

Assuming two list parameters, one for actors, one for directors:

```
MATCH (director:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
WHERE director.name in $directors
WITH m, count(director) as directorCount
WHERE directorCount = size($directors)
AND all(actor IN $actors WHERE (:Person {name:actor})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m))
RETURN m.title as Title
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that's another useful way to go about it as well!